# How do I remove the backup app after uninstalling the app?

Tags: android, backup, uninstallation

I uninstalled the application and reinstall the application again. The previous data seems like it still visible in newly installed application even though it was uninstalled previously. I saw some forum, the later android version will backup your app's data after uninstalling the app.

Is there a way to remove those backup app's data as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps -

1. Navigate to Settings
2. Apps
3. Search for you app name in the list
4. Now open it and tap on Clear Cache and clear Data
5. Uninstall the installed app
6. Now install the app again

The above steps should help you to resolve your problem

Comment: Not possible as there wont be any instances of the app in your app list

Comment: But the app is uninstalled right? So how can you access the cache once it's uninstalled, as it's no longer in the app list?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this feature for your app by adding the following line in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application
...
    android:allowBackup="false"
...
>
```

Comment: This was helped in my case.

Comment: allowBackup is deprecated from Android 12